# CodenameOne: Getting Error while click on Menu Item

Tags: android, ios, nullpointerexception, codenameone

I have developed app using codename one.It was working fine initially.but since 3-4 days getting issues.When I clicked on `Menu` Item it giving below error

> `an internal application error occurred:java.lang.NullPointerException:Attempt to invoke virtual method'void com.codename1.o.al.bj() on null object refference`

Iniially every thing was working fine but since 3-4 days it giving issues like that.
Please help me to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Jonas's answer is correct this should work in the next update and his workaround should work too

Answer (score 2):

I have submited an issue last Friday. This is due to the last update and will be fixed on the next update (next Friday). You can workaround it by disabling the on top side menu for now with: `yourForm.getToolbar().setOnTopSideMenu(false);`

Answer (score 1):

We can not analyse what went wrong, because error is a generic "Null Pointer Exception". We need to know complete functionality and what different behaviour happened. Please provide us with some more details if possible.

Comment: Put it as a comment rather than posting it as a sperate answer.

Comment: Actually It was working fine.but a day before yesterday  I sent build for apk file .After that those issues has been occured.